# SonataAdminBundle's menu labels tree shows entity path instead entity name

Tags: php, xml, sonata-admin

it's my first question on SO. I have a problem with SonataAdminBundle. Everythink works fine, but instead name of entity field i get a path to entity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="sonata.admin.city" class="My\FrontendBundle\Admin\CityAdmin">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="Dane" label="Miasta"/>
            <argument />
            <argument>My\FrontendBundle\Entity\City</argument>
            <argument>SonataAdminBundle:CRUD</argument>
            <call method="setTranslationDomain">
                <argument>MyFrontendBundle</argument>
            </call>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Php class

```
namespace My\FrontendBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class CityAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected $translationDomain = 'MyFrontendBundle'; 
    //protected $baseRoutePattern = 'city';
    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'City name'))
            ->add('population', 'number') //if no type is specified, SonataAdminBundle tries to guess it
        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on filter forms
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('name')
            ->add('population','number')
        ;
    }
}
```

Photo: [image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to define `__toString()` method in your entity that is linked with your admin `My\FrontendBundle\Entity\City` and return name of the city in case of edit for add case return your desired text

```
class City {

    public function __toString() {

        return ( $this->id ) ? $this->getName(): 'New City';

    }
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define/override `toString()` method in your admin class:

```
class CityAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function toString($object)
    {
       return (!$object || !$object->getId()) ? 'New City' : $object->getName();
    }

    ...

}
```